# Date Range for Facebook Graph API request on posts level

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unix-timestamp

I am working on a tool for my company created to get data from our Facebook publications. It has not been working for a while, so I have to get all the historical data from June to November 2018.

My two scripts (one that get title and type of publication, and the other that get the number of link clicks) are working well to get data from last pushes, but when I try to add a date range in my Graph API request, I have some issues:

- the regular query is `[page_id]/posts?fields=id,created_time,link,type,name`
- the query for historical data is `[page_id]/posts?fields=id,created_time,link,type,name,since=1529280000&until=1529712000`, as the API is supposed to work with unixtime
  I get perfect results for regular use, but the results for historical data only shows video publications in Graph API Explorer, with a debug message saying:

> The since field does not exist on the PagePost object.

Same for "until" field when not using "since". I tried to replace "posts/" with "feed/" but it returned the exact same result...

Do you have any idea of how to get all the publications from a Page I own on a certain date range?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that it is not possible to request this kind of data unfortunately, third party services must be used...